# Next 13.4 where is the api Folder?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a question regarding Next 13.4. Since today I can only use Next 13.4. I wonder where the api folder has gone. It is no longer created in this version. It still worked in 13.3. How can I now make a POST or GET request and the result with NextResponse return?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: There isn't.
With 13.4 the Next Team released the app directory as stable. So probably you used this feature while setting up your project. Here a [link](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-4) to the NextJS Blog related to the release.

While reading through the official Docs I stumbled uppon [this Information](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers#:%7E:text=Good%20to%20know,Route%20Handlers%20together).
In short: That's the equivalent to the API Routes in the pages directory.

Answer (score 20):

If there isn't any /api folder, you can make one inside /app folder.

In Next 13.4, the api endpoints are treated as route.js, just like page.js.

e.g
/app/api/home/route.js

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function GET() {
  return NextResponse.json({ name: 'Anuj Singh' });
}
```

so from browser if you navigate to /api/home
you will see the result.\

More info on this from official doc : https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers

Answer (score 5):

You can still use API routes with `pages/api` directory, [they will continue to work](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#api-routes) without any changes. If you have an ongoing project you don't have to migrate it right now, you can still stick to an old way for a while, for example. If you have used some sort of CLI which does not create this folder, you can do it yourself manually.

However there is a new Next.js v13.4 feature called [Route Handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers). It is only available inside the `app` directory. It is the equivalent of API Routes meaning you do not need to use API Routes and Route Handlers together. If you are starting a new project you might want to start with Route Handlers right away.

Comment: Yes, it works quite differently. I have not tried it yet, but if you have concrete question you can probably post it as a separate question, maybe someone knows!

Answer (score 3):

To build off of [Anuj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22022723/anuj-singh).

NextJS 13.4 changed from a "default" pages/api folder to one you have to create yourself.  You will very likely want to create a similar folder yourself `app/api`.

ANALOGY TO UNDERSTAND API ROUTES :: By the time that you're looking into this question, you've already figured out that pages in the new `app router` structure are rendered via a specific folder and file naming system -- ie. you set up the following folder + files `app/myPage/page.js` and the contents of the file `page.js` are what is rendered upon browsing to `http://localhost:3000/myPage`

API ROUTES WORK IN A SIMILAR WAY :: routing works in an analogous way with a specific folder + file naming system but using `route.js` is used instead of `page.js`

So two very simple examples.

Example 1: You can create the folder + file like this. `app/api/route.js` and in the file route.js put the following.
NOTE: These are not fully formed functions per HTTP VERB but illustrations to show how the new routing system works:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function GET() {
  return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Hello - GET' });
}

export async function POST() {
  return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Hello - POST' });
}

export async function PUT() {
  return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Hello - PUT' });
}

export async function DELETE() {
  return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Hello - DELETE' });
}
```

Test this by navigating to `http:localhost:3000/api` and you should see `{"message": "Hello - GET"}`.  Also, you can test the rest of the verbs in Postman using the url `http:localhost:3000/api` and toggling through the verbs GET/POST/PUT/DELETE on your request.

! NOTE - One thing that is great about this new system, is that you no longer have to do the multiple `if statements` on incoming request, each VERB gets its own function which I find to be cleaner.

```
// previous way
export default async function handler(req, res) {
 if (req.method === 'GET') { ... }
 if (req.method === 'POST') { ... }
 if (req.method === 'PUT') { ... }
 if (req.method === 'DELETE') { ... }
```

Example 2: To complete the example, you can create various routes as needed using the folder + file system.  Create a NEW folder and file: `app/api/myNewRoute/route.js` and in the file route.js put the following:  (NOTE: These are not fully formed functions per HTTP VERB but illustrations to show how the new routing system works.)

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function GET() {
  return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Hello - GET' });
}

export async function POST() {
  return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Hello - POST' });
}

export async function PUT() {
  return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Hello - PUT' });
}

export async function DELETE() {
  return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Hello - DELETE' });
}


export async function DELETE() {
  return NextResponse.json({ name: 'Hello - DELETE' });
}
```

Test this by navigating to `http:localhost:3000/api/myNewRoute` and you should see `{"message": "Hello - GET"}`.  Also, you can test the other HTTP verbs in Postman using the url `http:localhost:3000/api/myNewRoute` and toggling through the verbs GET/POST/PUT/DELETE.

Hope it helps, and if you want to read more here is [NextJS's doc on the subject.](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah looks like Next just expects us to create route handlers in the designated components themselves where the data is required. So just create route handlers in-component in server components.